# ¿Cómo comunico 2 fragments de un Tabbed Activity en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment, fragment

Hola lo que quiero poder hacer es pasar información de una variable de un fragment a otro, ambos fragment son de un Tabbed Activity llamado 'AppStuff', un fragment se llama 'Report' y otro 'Map'. Lo que me gustaria hacer es pasar de 'Map' una variable para mostrar la información en un TextView de 'Report'.

Este es mi código de la clase 'AppStuff' esta clase tiene la intención de hacer la comunicacion entre los fragment, cabe mencionar que esta clase extiende de AppCompatActivity.

```
public class AppStuff extends AppCompatActivity implements Map.DataListener {

@Override
    public void sendData(String text) {
        Report report = (Report) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myReport);
        report.renderAddress(text);
    }

}
```

Este es mi codigo del fragment 'Map' que es de donde quiero mandar la información.

```
private DataListener callBack;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        try {
            callBack = (DataListener) context;
        } catch (Exception e){
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " should implement DataListener");
        }

    }
    @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            myUbication();
            sendAddressInfo(address.getAddressLine(0).toLowerCase());
        }

        private void sendAddressInfo(String address){
            callBack.sendData(address);
        }

        public interface DataListener {
            void sendData(String text);
        }
```

El código del fragment en donde quiero recibir el dato se llama 'Report' y es este.

```
public void renderAddress(String address){
        txtAddress.setText(address);

    }
```

Parece que esta bien desde mi perspectiva, pero desde que implemente esto me dice que la aplicación deja de funcionar en cuanto se carga.